# VBA for list matching functions - Isnumber

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

SO I'm back sorting/matching lists from multiple trials in our lab

1. There is one master list of all the items found
2. Not all items that appear in the master list are found in each trial
3. I want to use VBA to match the POTENTIALLY found value in the experimental list and categorize it with a number so that it can be later sorted and aligned with other datasets.

so here is what I have thus far for EACH cell and it's only for 5 of my values...

```
IFS(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($K$7,C14))=TRUE,$J$7,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($K$8,C14))=TRUE,$J$8,(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($K$9,C14)))=TRUE,$J$9,(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($K$10,C14)))=TRUE,$J$10,(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($K$11,C14)))=TRUE,$J$11)
```

Block K is the Master List, Block J is my numbering function associated with this and block C is the actual output that changes each trial.

It would seem that some sort of combination of isnumber, multivariable problem with an offset built in would work but I'm coming up with too many errors.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: So to be clear you want to sift through C and look for matches in either J or K?

Comment: I want to sift through C and look for matches in K and then number the cell to the left of the identified value (which would be in B in the above instance) with the value in J. So Rows for B and C are equal and rows for J and K are equal (in my mind)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rephrase so as to ensure I understand you correctly

- Column K has a list of keywords
- Column J as a list of values associated with those keywords
- Column C has a phrase that might include a keyword from column K
- If the cell in column C contains that keyword, you want to return the value from Column J adjacent to the keyword in column K in Column B

The following formula will return the last "match".  Obviously you can extend the ranges for columns J:K as needed.

```
B14: =LOOKUP(2,1/SEARCH($K$7:$K$11,C14),$J$7:$J$11)
```

Potential issues, depending on your data, would be if a keyword is contained within a word in C14.  eg:  `Keyword: his`.  `c14: This is my stuff`  Since `his` is part of `this`, a match would be flagged.

If that issue might cause a problem, depending on your data structure, it might require a minor change in the code; or a VBA solution.

Also, if you might have multiple matches, a VBA solution would be simpler.

Here is a VBA solution that makes similar assumptions as above.

- Your data starts in `C14` and extends downward.  There is nothing below
- Codes find in the data will be in `B14` (and multiple codes for the same `C14` contents will be separated by `comma-space`
- Keywords will start in `K7` and extend down
- Codes for these keywords will be in the adjacent row in column `J`
- only whole words will be found (words within longer words will not be matched)
- Regular Expressions are used to do the matching.

  - With Regex, `\b` signifies a word boundary.
  - A word boundary is the point at which a word character is adjacent to a non-word character, or the beginning or end of the line.

    - A word character is a character in the set of `[A-Za-z0-9_]` (alphabet letters, digits, and the underscore)
  - If this does not adequately describe the word boundaries in your data, a different algorithm could be used.

Enjoy

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub ListMatch()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim rCodeData As Range, rCodeKeyWord As Range
    Dim vCodeData, vCodeKeyWord
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
    Dim I As Long, J As Long

Set WS = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'or whatever
With WS
    'data in C14:Cn 'relevant code adjacent in column B
    Set rCodeData = .Range(.Cells(14, 3), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)).Offset(columnoffset:=-1).Resize(columnsize:=2)

    'codes and keywords in J7:Kn
    Set rCodeKeyWord = .Range(.Cells(7, 10), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=2)
End With

'read into arrays for speed of execution
vCodeData = rCodeData
vCodeKeyWord = rCodeKeyWord

'initialize regex
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .ignorecase = True

    'go through the data and look for keywords
    For I = 1 To UBound(vCodeData, 1)
        vCodeData(I, 1) = ""
        For J = 1 To UBound(vCodeKeyWord, 1)
            .Pattern = "\b" & vCodeKeyWord(J, 2) & "\b"
            If .test(vCodeData(I, 2)) = True Then
                vCodeData(I, 1) = vCodeData(I, 1) & ", " & vCodeKeyWord(J, 1)
            End If
        Next J
        vCodeData(I, 1) = Mid(vCodeData(I, 1), 3)
    Next I
End With

rCodeData = vCodeData

End Sub
```

---

Comment: Thanks Ron! Not 100% sure how to manipulate regex code but it all seems to work! I may post again as I try to expand this more broadly!